# Find longest substring of text and pattern

Tags: python, text-processing

Is there a a function in Python, which returns an index of the longest common substring of text and a given pattern in case that pattern has to start with this substring?

```
text = Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit
pattern = amegt
```

> > > 22

Comment: Can you explain your example? what is "pattern" and how come the answer is 22 ?

Comment: I don't think so, but this is a [well-studied computer science problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem), so you could make your own.

Comment: @alfasin - if I understand correctly, it returns 22 because that's the index in `text` where the longest common substring of `text` and `pattern` starts, specifically the string `ame`.

Comment: @Milan           what if you have multiple matches? are you gonna represent the index of the first match? e.g. if `amegt` appears three times in a search string (locations, 5, 12, 23), will you report 5?

Comment: @ha9u63ar Yes, I will report 5 for example.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the "suffix tree" algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Your solution should be this: https://github.com/kvh/Python-Suffix-Tree

There is an example there on how to use the library. It does exactly what you need as far as i understand from your requirements.

Let me know if you need additional help.

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have a little different problem from what lcsp problem. There is a condition - the substring has to be a prefix of the text

Comment: So, if you have the substring "abcde", and if you have "abc" and "bcde" in the main string, then you want the index where "abc" is. Am i correct in my understanding?

Comment: @Milan so in that case your suffix tree will contain only one branch with all the prefixes. Shouldn't be difficult to modify the python code to generate such a branch instead of the whole suffix tree.

Comment: That's correct. You basically need to change the part where the branches are checked and validated, you need to change the validation so that it starts with the start of the substring.